# docusign access code authentication mail

Tags: docusignapi

If I set the recipients to get Access Code through email, then do I need to program separately to send the email with access code or Docusign API will automatically send the access code email to all recipients? 
Also do I need to enable any setting from my DocuSign account to turn on this feature? I have a developer Docusign Account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the `Access Code` authentication feature, it's up to the sender how to actually get the code over to the signer.  For example, if you have their phone number you can call them and give it to them.  Or you can instant message them or send an SMS, or some other means.  In general though I would shy away from sending them the code through email as that pretty much defeats the purpose of multi-factor authentication (i.e. if someone has compromised their email they will get both the signature request email AND the access code email).

Similarly, the `SMS Authentication` feature is used the same way but in this case the code is explicitly sent to their mobile phone number.  With Access Code it's up to you how to provide to the recipient.

Comment: I got your point of sending Access code through email. But it is a project requirement. So my question is if its sending access code via email then do I need to code explicitly(using mailclient class etc. in C#) to send the code to the recipient or i just need to set the flag and accesscode in docusign request object and Docusign in turn will send the access code in email to the recipient?

Comment: I got it. It looks like I have to set one more parameter "AddAccessCodeToEmailSpecified" in my API call so that docusign wil include the access code in email.